# Gitlab CI pipeline - continue to next stage only on a certain condition

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to build a Gitlab pipeline that is made up of 4 jobs. The stages I have are:

```
stages:
- compare
- build
- test
- deploy
```

The compare stage is taking a dump from an API on another server, comparing it to the same dump from the last successful pipeline run (it's made available as an artifact) then comparing the two.
If there is any difference I would like the pipeline to move onto the next stage, if there is no difference then I would like it to exit gracefully.

I have it working but rather than exiting gracefully if there are no differences it fails and the pipeline is marked as failed, here is how it looks.

[image]

Here is the important code from my .gitlab-ci.yaml (with some identifying information removed )

```
Get_inventory_dump:
  stage: compare  
  only:
    - schedules
  script: 
    - 'curl -k --output "previous-inventory.json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $user_token" "https://url/to/get/artifact/from/last/successful/run"'
    - python3 auto_config_scripts/dump_device_inventory_api_to_json.py -p $pass -o /inventory.json -u https://url/for/inventory/dump -y
    - /usr/bin/cmp previous-inventory.json inventory.json && echo "No Change in inventory since last successful run" && exit 1 || echo "Inventory has changed since last run, continue" && exit 0
  artifacts:
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 4 weeks
    paths:
     - inventory.json

Generate_icinga_config:
  stage: build
  only:
    - schedules
  when: on_success
  script:
```

Everything is behaving as I would expect but I feel like there is a better way to do this.

Is there a way, if the comparison is the same to simply skip the next stages of the pipeline but still have the pipeline completed as 'passed' rather than 'failed'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on Fzgregors suggestion, this is how I solved my problem:
If there was a difference and I wanted my second stage to actually do some work I created a file called "continue" and made it available as an artifact.

The second stage will look for that file and use an IF statement to decide if it should do something or just exit nicely

```
Get_inventory_dump:
  stage: compare  
  only:
    - schedules
  script: 
    - 'curl -k --output "previous-inventory.json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $user_token" "https://url/to/get/artifact/from/last/successful/run"'
    - python3 auto_config_scripts/dump_device_inventory_api_to_json.py -p $pass -o /inventory.json -u https://url/for/inventory/dump -y
    - /usr/bin/cmp previous-inventory.json inventory.json && echo "No Change in inventory since last successful run" || echo "Inventory has changed since last run, continue" && touch continue
  artifacts:
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 4 weeks
    paths:
     - inventory.json
     - continue

Generate_icinga_config:
  stage: build
  only:
    - schedules
  when: on_success
  script: 
    - if [[ -f continue ]]; then
        do some stuff;
      else
        echo "No Change in inventory, nothing to do";
      fi
```

This allowed me to keep my inventory artifact but at the same time let the next stage know if it needed to do some work or just do nothing and exit with code 0

Comment: shouldn't the `Generate_icinga_config` job have a `dependency: Get_inventory_dump`?

Answer (score 6):

There are two solutions I can think of. Unfortunately, they either come slightly confusing UI behavior or you have to adapt all jobs.

Job attributes like `only` or `changes` are only concerned with the state of or the files of the git repository (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) and therefore not of use here as the file is only created during CI and not part of the repository.

Solution 1: You can `allow_failure: true` to the first job. This will mark the pipeline as successful despite the job failing and subsequent jobs will not be executed as the first job did not succeed. The drawback is that when you investigate the pipeline there will be an exclamation mark instead of a green check for this job.

Solution 2: Instead of failing the first job when there are no changes the `inventory.json` file is removed. And all subsequent jobs directly terminate with exit code 0 when the file doesn't exist. Note that this only works because `inventory.json` is marked as an artifact.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I prefer Solution 2 as my pipeline will always pass even if the 2nd, 3rd, 4th jobs have nothing to do.
I tried removing the inventory.json file but then it wasn't able to make it available as an artifact and therefore broke future runs so I adjusted your method slightly. If it found a difference it touched a file called continue which was made available as an artifact. If the file exists then my next job will run some commands, if not it will do nothing but exit nicely. Not sure how easy that is to understand so I'll answer my own question with the sample code

Answer (score 0):

I have a substantially similar construction and I'm looking for essentially the same solution.

When I `allow_failure: true` my subsequent jobs DO execute.

If I use a stamp file, all of the subsequent jobs also execute taking up queue, runners, etc, even though they aren't needed.

I was hoping for an easier solution but I think I'm going to have to go with generated yaml files.  That seems to be the only way to inject dynamic information like decisions into a pipeline.